# Spacing photos on gallery page not working

Tags: css, shadowbox

I have the page working otherwise but the spacing isn't when added to the main.css page...

Here is a codepen of what I have working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQxxyJ.`enter code here`

Here is the codepen that has my main.css file (disregard the HTML): https://codepen.io/AJ2021/pen/pQzmOR`enter code here`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a minimal code snippet to the question don't link to a page and expect us to dig trough the code to find out what is wrong. Also the 2 linked codepens vary too much

Comment: This is the CSS code that I can't seem to get working: #gallery img {padding: 10px; margin: 5px;background: green}  I added it to my main.css file at the end and no spacing but when I put that in the codepen just by itself with the HTML code it works.

Comment: @JacksonLawton, the codepen examples don't let me see your main.css file, so I can't check why your CSS isn't working. If it's working in the codepen, then that makes me suspect that a) the main.css file might not be coming in properly, or maybe b) there are two or more CSS rules conflcting. But we'll need to see more code to know more.

Comment: Yes it does... https://codepen.io/AJ2021/pen/pQzmORenter code here has the main.css file in the css section. Everything up to line 100 is in the main.css file the rest you can ignore as it is not need anymore. Let me know if you still can’t see it.